# Get checkbox status on Outlook Backstage?

Tags: c#, xml, outlook-addin

With Outlook 2010: if I have a checkbox defined in XML for the backstage to load, how can I query that element and get its status with C#? Here's an example of the backstage XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <backstage>
    <tab id="MyBackstageTab"
         getVisible="MyBackstageTab_GetVisible">
      <firstColumn>
        <group id="RegularGroup">
          <bottomItems>
            <groupBox id="GeneralGroupBox">

              <!-- This works fine; onAction is called every click. -->
              <button id="ApplyButton"
                      label="Apply"
                      onAction="ButtonAction"/>

              <!-- Neither onAction or getPressed functions are called
                   when interacting with the checkbox on the form. -->
              <checkBox id="AddInEnabled"
                        label="Enable AddIn"
                        onAction="CheckBoxAction"
                        getPressed="CheckBoxPressed"/>

            </groupBox>
          </bottomItems>
        </group>
      </firstColumn>
    </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```

...and here's the `MyRibbon.cs`:

```
namespace MyAddIn {

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility {

        // constructors, etc...

        public void ButtonAction(Office.IRibbonControl control) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                "ButtonAction: " + control.Id);
        }

        // Never gets called.
        public void CheckBoxAction(Office.IRibbonControl control) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                "CheckBoxAction: " + control.Id);
        }

        // Never gets called.
        public void CheckBoxPressed(Office.IRibbonControl control) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                "CheckBoxPressed: " + control.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

My thinking is to record each elements' status, inside the `MyRibbon` class, as events are fired when the user interacts with the form. However, since some things (like the `checkbox` in my example above) don't seem to trigger any usable events, I need some other way to query the backstage from within this class.

So if I have an *Apply* button that will save the form state somewhere (representing AddIn settings): I can react to that button being clicked, but how can I also get the `checkbox` state at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [How to access backstage checkbox value in an Office addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039187/how-to-access-backstage-checkbox-value-in-an-office-addin/8050834#8050834)

*ps: I found your question after writing mine* :)