# How to access backstage checkbox value in an Office addin?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have a boolean property `Settings.Default.MarkAsRead` in the Setting.settings file, which I can access in my Ribbon class. What I'd like to do is set the value of a check box in my backstage section depending on the value of this property. Also if the user modifies it, I'll need to save the new value.

Any way I can do this?

This is my (simplified) xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
  <backstage>
    <tab id="MyBackstageSection" label="MyBackstageSection"
                columnWidthPercent="30" insertAfterMso="TabInfo" visible="true" >
      <firstColumn>
        <group id="grpOne" label="Configuration">
          <bottomItems>

              <checkBox id="markAsRead" label="Mark as read"
                                 getPressed="markAsRead_GetPressed" />

              <button id="save" label="Save Preferences" onAction="save_Click"/>

          </bottomItems>         
        </group>
      </firstColumn>
    </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a way to access the xml elements from the `Ribbon_Load` method, so I've created a boolean property in the ribbon class that I update using the `GetPressed` and `OnAction` callbacks:

xml:

```
<checkBox id="markAsRead" label="Mark as read" 
            onAction="markAsRead_OnAction" getPressed="markAsRead_GetPressed"/>
```

c#:

```
    private bool MarkAsRead { get; set; }

    public bool markAsRead_GetPressed(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        this.MarkAsRead = Settings.Default.MarkAsRead;
        return this.MarkAsRead;
    }

    public void markAsRead_OnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool isPressed)
    {
        this.MarkAsRead = isPressed;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was searching for months !
These are not even given in Microsoft MSDN Backstage control reference !!

Thanks a lot man.